# JQuery UI Slider in Highcharts using more then one datapoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I found a nice example of an implementation of the JQuery UI slider in Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/bdNnm/

This is exactly what I want, except for having more then one column. I don't know how to setup the data structure for doing this. I there a solution for this?

This is what the code looks like:

```
$(function () {
    function updateChart(chart, value) {
        chart.series[0].setData([data1[value]]);
    }

    function chartIncrement(identifier, value) {
        $("#slider-val").text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', data1[value][0]));
        updateChart(chart, value);
    }

    var slideIt = true;
    var data1 = [
        [1362200400000, 5.20],
        [1364875200000, 5.00],
        [1367467200000, 5.60],
        [1370145600000, 5.90],
        [1372737600000, 5.80],
        [1375416000000, 5.50],
        [1378094400000, 5.30],
        [1380686400000, 5.50],
        [1383364800000, 5.00],
        [1385960400000, 4.80]
    ];

    var yMaxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, data1.map(function (o) {
        return o[1];
    }));
    yMaxVal = Math.ceil(yMaxVal);

    $("#slider-val").text(Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', data1[0][0]));

    // Build the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'column',
            borderColor: '#EBBA95',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: null,
            min: 0,
            max: yMaxVal,
            tickInterval: 2
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: null,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Labor Force',
            data: [data1[0]],
            color: '#729fcf'
        }]
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#yearSlider').slider({
            value: 0,
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: data1.length - 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                chartIncrement(this, ui.value);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                chartIncrement(this, ui.value);
            }
        });
    });

    function scrollSlider() {
        if (!slide_it) return false;

        var slideValue;
        slideValue = $("#yearSlider").slider("value");
        if (slideValue >= 0) {
            if (slideValue == data1.length - 1) {
                slideValue = -1;
            }
            $("#yearSlider").slider("value", slideValue + 1);
            setTimeout(scrollSlider, 1000);
        }
    }

    $('#startSlider').click(function () {
        var playPause = $("#startSlider").prop('value');
        //console.log(playPause);
        if (playPause == "Play") {
            window.slide_it = true;
            scrollSlider();
            $("#startSlider").prop('value', 'Pause');
        } else {
            window.slide_it = false;
            //console.log(playPause);
            $("#startSlider").prop('value', 'Play');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this without drastically changing your data structure. Here's the fiddle: [**LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/taylanaydinli/ocngcktu/2/)

So now your data structure looks like this:

```
var data1 = [
    //               *s1* *s2*  **you can add other series**
    [1362200400000, 5.20, 5.40],
    [1364875200000, 5.00, 5.20],
    [1367467200000, 5.60, 5.80],
    [1370145600000, 5.90, 6.10],
    [1372737600000, 5.80, 6.00],
    [1375416000000, 5.50, 5.70],
    [1378094400000, 5.30, 5.50],
    [1380686400000, 5.50, 5.70],
    [1383364800000, 5.00, 5.20],
    [1385960400000, 4.80, 5.00]
];
```

It's basically a matrix. All columns after the first column are data for a new series.

I changed the `updateChart` function so it updates each series instead of the hardcoded `series[0]`. It doesn't have to know how many series there are.

```
function updateChart(chart, value) {
    for(i=0; i<chart.series.length; i++) {
        // update each series
        chart.series[i].setData([data1[value][i+1]]);
    }
}
```

I also had to jump through some hoops with the `getMaxYValue` function so it will find the max value among all series data.

Of course, there is also the option of changing the structure of `data1` to make finding the max value relatively easier. But I don't know what you were trying to achieve with this and I don't know how robust a code you need, so I went with the most conservative approach and changed as little of your code as possible.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. However my goal seems to be more complicated then I thought before. What I'm trying to establish is a population pyramid like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zwakhall/kbbub7t5/ that can be controlled with a slider. With the current data structure It's not possible to add separate category names for every column. It is also not possible to control the male and female figures opposite to each other. As you mentioned, may be the data structure needs to be changed. Any suggestions are more then welcome.

Comment: The solution I was looking for is the Motion Highcharts plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/40/Motion
I think this is the best solution.
Thanks for any help.